# How to solve two dimensional growth grid problem?

Tags: java, optimization, multidimensional-array

I was doing an assessment for job interview. One of the 3 problems that I had to solve in an hour was finding the maximal value in a grid where you traverse it and add 1 to the elements based on the coordinates given. I spent a little to much time on the second problem and only ended up with about 20 minutes for this one. I didn't finish it in time so it's bugging me.

I just want to make sure that the solution to the problem as I remember it is optimized.

The input is a String array of two int values and the dimension of the grid.

To illustrate, if the coordinates given are (3,2) (2,2) (1,3) then

```
[1][1][0]     
[1][1][0]     
[1][1][0]     

[1][1][0]     
[2][2][0]     
[2][2][0]     

[1][1][0]
[2][2][0]
[3][3][1]
```

and so on...

I believe the required result was the maximal value that is not in (1,1) and the number of times it exists in the grid.

This is the the solution I came up with. Is there any way to optimize it?

```java
public static List<Integer> twoDimensions(String[] coordinates, int n) {

    List<Integer> maxAndCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[][] grid = new int[n][n];
    int arrLength = coordinates.length;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

        String[] coors = coordinates[i].split(" ");
        int row = Integer.parseInt(coors[0]);
        int column = Integer.parseInt(coors[1]);

        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < column; k++) {

                grid[j][k] += 1;
                System.out.println("grid (" + j + "," + k + "): " + grid[j][k]);

                if (!(j == 0 & k == 0) && grid[j][k] > max) {

                    max = grid[j][k];
                    count = 1;

                } else if (grid[j][k] == max) {

                    count++;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    maxAndCount.add(max);
    maxAndCount.add(count);

    return maxAndCount;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] coors = { "1 3", "2 4", "4 1", "3 2" };
    System.out.println("The Max and count Are:" + twoDimensions(coors, 4).toString());
}
```

Comment: I assume in your diagram, (1,1) starts from bottom left? I say this because in programming (1,1) usually starts from top left. I see that you already did row-major order (the first number in a coordinate refers to the vertical distance)

Comment: Also I think if the rectangle to add always start from (1,1), then after removing (1,1) the maximum will always be in (1,2) or (2,1), so finding max is just comparing those two values, returning the larger one. Perhaps there are other conditions that you haven't mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

Other solution for exercise is. (erikdhv@gmail.com)

```
public static long countMax(List<String> upRight) {
    // Write your code here
    int xl = 1;
    int yl = 1;

    xl = Integer.parseInt(upRight.get(1).split(" ")[0]);
    yl = Integer.parseInt(upRight.get(1).split(" ")[1]);

    for (int i=0; i<upRight.size(); i++){
        if (xl > Integer.parseInt(upRight.get((int) i).split(" ")[0]) ) xl = Integer.parseInt(upRight.get((int) i).split(" ")[0]);
        if (yl > Integer.parseInt(upRight.get((int) i).split(" ")[1])) yl = Integer.parseInt(upRight.get((int) i).split(" ")[1]);
    }

    return (yl * xl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of erik fails for few test cases, just change int to long for xl and yl and boom... all test cases passed.

Answer (score 0):

This fails a few test cases I can think of, the value of XL should be on Index 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long twoDimensions(List<String> list, int n) {
    long res = 0;
    int rowCount =0,colCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int row = list.get(i).charAt(0) - 48;
        int col = list.get(i).charAt(2) - 48;
        if(row > rowCount)
            rowCount = row;
        if(col >colCount)
            colCount = col;
    }
    int tempArr[][] = new int[rowCount+1][colCount+1];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int row = list.get(i).charAt(0) - 48;
        int col = list.get(i).charAt(2) - 48;
        for(int j=row;j>=1;j--)
        {
            int m = j;
        for(int k=1;k<=col;k++)
        {
            tempArr[m][k]= tempArr[m][k]+1;
            if(tempArr[m][k]>res)
                res = tempArr[m][k];
        }
        }
        System.out.println("for row: "+row+" col: "+col);
        for(int j = 0;j<=rowCount;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<=colCount;k++)
            {
                System.out.print(""+tempArr[j][k]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return res;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).